# Unencoded Ampersands and Capitalize

Tags: html, css, urlencode, ampersand, capitalize

Gretings all,

I'm wondering if anyone has noticed this inconsistency and has any idea how to fix it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p5G2N/

**Premise:**

Severals words are joined by an unencoded ampersand; There are no spaces.

`<p>Goodevening&goodnight</p>`

**Results:**

Chrome/IE:  Fails to interpret the character as an ampersand which breaks the intended capitalization styling.  Displays as: **Goodevening&Goodnight** [INCORRECT - Notice the capital G of goodnight, there should be no capitalization as it's a single word]

Firefox:  Manages to interpret the un-encoded ampersand properly and sees the string as a single word.  Displays as: **Goodevening&goodnight** [CORRECT]

**Question:**

How do I get Chrome/IE to respect the styling (capitalize)?

Comment: Afaik, ampersands are not allowed in HTML source code as literals, i.e. they have to be written as `&amp;`

Comment: It's also worth noting that in this example if you were to type "guitar&amplifer" even Firefox would render this **correctly** as `guitar&Lifier`. I think that's a pretty good example of why you *shouldn't* use `&` over `&amp`.

Answer (score 3):

`&amp` *should* be used over `&`. From the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2):

> Authors should use `"&amp;"` (ASCII decimal 38) instead of `"&"` to avoid confusion with the beginning of a character reference (entity reference open delimiter). Authors should also use `"&amp;"` in attribute values since character references are allowed within CDATA attribute values.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas To be fair, HTML5 might include an ultimately unhelpful multiple-paragraph explanation on what heuristics to use to determine what exactly should be done with the &.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Your expectation is incorrect. `goodbye&goodnight` has two word-separation points, one on each side of the ampersand. Whether the ampersand is encoded or not is irrelevant.

---

As far as I know, CSS doesn't fully specify what a "word" is, but there is a recommendation to use the Unicode standard word separation algorithm, which you can find [here (UAX29)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).

An informal summary is that a word is a sequence of letters, numbers or "Connector_Punctuation" symbols (ties), and possibly containing "MidLetter", "MidNum" or "MidNumLet" symbols (there's a list in the referenced document), depending on the immediate context of the symbol. `&` is not in any of those categories, so a UAX29-conformant word-separation algorithm should split words before and after an `&`.

A word separation algorithm may take language into account. Indeed, it may do just about anything, but it's supposed to be unsurprising for a native speaker of the language. Non-programmers would probably be surprised if `word&word` were considered one word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `&`-symbol in HTML, use `&amp;` instead.